# Wet vent for toilet

Tags: plumbing

I have a vertical drain (and vent as it goes up to the attic) in my basement that a water softener and a sink both drain into.  If my toilet is 5' away from this 2" line, would the toilet be vented by this 2" vertical drain/vent that the softener and sink tie into? Sink is in bathroom and softener is in utility room.

Comment: why do you expect anyone here to know how the plumbing in your house is arranged? ... try to determine if the toilet is vented by that stack .... plug the top of the stack, flush the toilet ... if the water in the sink trap gets sucked out, then the toilet is most likely vented by that stack

Comment: @jsotola trying to learn what is acceptable distance for the vent and if that is not overloaded already

Comment: Toilets are typically on a 4" line. Do you have a 4" line connected to a 2" line? It kind of sounds like that by the way you've worded things.